# Unable to make rest api calls to ignite on local host

Tags: postman, ignite

I am referring this document https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/setup

I have downloaded the Ignite 2.15.0 binaries

and followed every steps of setting up and rest-api document

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/setup
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/restapi#ignite-quick-start-guide-for-rest-api

I have java version 18

I can see when I ran two nodes with default configurations (as suggested in docs), i can see the proper command line entries.

However, when i try to make a rest call,

by `curl "http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=version"`

it fails with the error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080`

Even though the document clearly saying that there isn't any additional configuration needed for it, is there anything I am missing?

Comment: It won’t be tested with Java 18. Do you get the same error with Java 17?

Comment: Did you copy `ignite-rest-http` to the `{IGNITE_HOME}/libs` directory?
Also, can you try to start the node in verbose mode using `ignite.sh -v` and check the output for the `Command protocol successfully started [name=Jetty REST, host=/0.0.0.0, port=8080]` message, to be sure that port 8080 is used.

Comment: Highly likely another application is using 8080. Try to change the REST port -DIGNITE_JETTY_PORT=9999

Comment: @IgorBelyakov Yes, that was missing. After putting ignite-rest-http into libs, rest calls started working. Thanks a lot. Can you please put it in answer so i can accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of Apache Ignite binary distribution usage, it's required to move the `ignite-rest-http` module from the `{IGNITE_HOME}/libs/optional/` directory to the `{IGNITE_HOME}/libs` to enable REST API.

More details regarding REST API configuration can be found [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/restapi).